# Is this sentence correct? ""although, that response was different in my expectation"

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions, british-english

When I received some idea from A person, I'd like to say like this

"although, that response was different in my expectation".

But I'm not sure about this is correct or not.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you want to say?  What does "although" add to your sentence?  We usually use the *although* to qualify something, like "We have some food, although not as much as we would like."

Answer (score 1):

[Diffent from, than or to? - Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/different-from-than-or-to)

You can use either of these 3, **from** being the most used across the world. 
**Different in**, as far as I know, doesn't exist as an idiom. But you could encounter:

> These cases are **different in** (the fact) **that** they involve different persons.

In your sentence, you would thus say:

> Although, that response was **different from** my expectations.

**Expectations** is  way more often used in plural form, even though its singular peer doesn't seem grammatically wrong.